# How to model crumpled clothing?

Tags: modeling, cloth-simulation

I have a pants model on top of a character model. I want to add wrinkles to the pants to make it look baggy. how do I do that?

Comment: you could use the sculpt tools on a high-poly version, then bake to use this on the low-poly version. Or add edge loops and move some vertices.

Comment: Hello and welcome to BSE (this is the traditional greetings). Surely, if you want to have some feedback you should show (image, mesh, etc.) of what the pants looks like in the mesh you have.